# Integrate the results of one javascript function into another

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have been having trouble integrating both these scripts in to my HTML page.

Firstly, I have one javascript that compiles the results of dropdown boxes and text boxes into a string text. That works fine.

The second javascript creates a txt file that can be downloaded (in a multiline array). What I am trying to do is get the results of the string made in `function generate()` to appear as a single line in the array of javascript download command...

FYI - I have all this in one html file since its light weight...

Thanks in advance for your help!

```js
function generate(){
    var result = '';

    result += document.getElementById('drop1').value + ' - ';
    result += document.getElementById('drop2').value + ' - ';
    result += document.getElementById('drop3').value + ' - ';
    result += document.getElementById('text1').value + ' - ';
    result += document.getElementById('text2').value;

 document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;
}
generate();

function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);
  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

function getLastUpdated() {
  return result;
}

// Start file download.
document.getElementById("dwn-btn").addEventListener('click', function(){
  // Generate download of hello.txt file with some content
  var text = [
    'A rather long string of English text, an error message',
    getLastUpdated(),
    'end'
  ].join('\n');

  var filename = "hello.txt";

  download(filename, text.replace(/\n/g, '\r\n')); // Convert LF ro CRLF
}, false);
```

```html
<select id="drop1" onchange="generate()">
    <option value="d1s1">D1 S1</option>
    <option value="d1s2">D1 S2</option>
</select>
<select id="drop2" onchange="generate()">
    <option value="d2s1">D2 S1</option>
    <option value="d2s2">D2 S2</option>
</select>
<select id="drop3" onchange="generate()">
    <option value="d3s1">D3 S1</option>
    <option value="d3s2">D3 S2</option>
</select>
<input id="text1" type="text" value="text1" onchange="generate()" onkeyup="generate()" />
<input id="text2" type="text" value="text2" onchange="generate()" onkeyup="generate()" />

<p id="output"></p>

<input type="button" id="dwn-btn" value="Download" />
```

Comment: Can we assume you mean `generate` and not `getgenerate`?

Comment: yeah, edited just now - sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to refer to the local `result` variable of the `generate` function in as though it were a global and available from inside `getLastUpdated`.  One fix would be to make that global.  There are all sorts of reasons that might be a bad idea.  Better would be to make the code that generates that text available from inside your `generate` function and from the listener that generates your download text.  To do this, I changed `getLastUpdate` to do the actual calculation, then called it from inside `generate` and from that listener.  The big point is the `return` statement.  Functions that don't return anything scare me!  :smile:

```js
function getLastUpdated() {
    var result = '';

    result += document.getElementById('drop1').value + ' - ';
    result += document.getElementById('drop2').value + ' - ';
    result += document.getElementById('drop3').value + ' - ';
    result += document.getElementById('text1').value + ' - ';
    result += document.getElementById('text2').value;
    return result;
}

function generate(){
  var result = getLastUpdated()
 document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;
}
generate();

function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);
  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
  document.body.removeChild(element);
}


// Start file download.
document.getElementById("dwn-btn").addEventListener('click', function(){
  // Generate download of hello.txt file with some content
  var text = [
    'A rather long string of English text, an error message',
    getLastUpdated(),
    'end'
  ].join('\n');

  var filename = "hello.txt";

  download(filename, text.replace(/\n/g, '\r\n')); // Convert LF ro CRLF
}, false);
```

```html
<select id="drop1" onchange="generate()">
    <option value="d1s1">D1 S1</option>
    <option value="d1s2">D1 S2</option>
</select>
<select id="drop2" onchange="generate()">
    <option value="d2s1">D2 S1</option>
    <option value="d2s2">D2 S2</option>
</select>
<select id="drop3" onchange="generate()">
    <option value="d3s1">D3 S1</option>
    <option value="d3s2">D3 S2</option>
</select>
<input id="text1" type="text" value="text1" onchange="generate()" onkeyup="generate()" />
<input id="text2" type="text" value="text2" onchange="generate()" onkeyup="generate()" />

<p id="output"></p>

<input type="button" id="dwn-btn" value="Download" />
```

Comment: You sir are magician! Thank you. I am learning as I go and stackoverflow is super helpful. many thanks :)

Comment: so I tried this code on my website and on Html editor 3.5V and the download button wont initiate the command ... however here it works just fine ... suggestions? https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRBDA70PS8WT

Comment: At a guess, it's because your script is running before the document is properly loaded.  Try moving the script block to the end of the body.  It works in **[this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/dxs3fmy2/)**, so you should be able to get it to work elsewhere.